# When should I use uv1 instead of uv0 on Unity Standard shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm wondering when should I use different `UV Set` options in the Unity Standard shader.

I know that UV stands for the texture coordinates, but what would I need to switch to `uv1` instead of `uv0`? I cannot see any immediate difference when I switch between them and Unity docs doesn't seem to explain much.

Perhaps somebody could shed some light on when different sets need to be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness: UV coordinates are assigned in model creation tools (Maya, Max, Blender etc.) not in Unity. So Unity just gives you access to a limited number of UV maps you may or may not have exported from afore-mentioned tools. That's why there isn't more documentation on UV sets, because they are an optional additional feature of an imported model.

There are scenarios in which more than one UV map is necessary or more elegant/performant. You can have shaders that use different UV coordinates for different maps. One example would be a shader that adds a detail map to a model which requires a different set of UV coordinates (independent from the base UV map which is used for the other maps like albedo, normals etc.)

You are not limited to switching between uv0 and uv1. You can use them in combination as well, if you create a shader that makes use of both maps. I think this is even more common than switching between different UV maps.